# Error showing int is equal to a boolean object

Tags: java

That's my confirmBooking method and im trying to check whether age is equal to a student or child so i can apply discounts wherever needed using an if statement. Also my boolean value is because i checked whether the age given was between some given numbers to determine whether it was a child or student. I get this error Customer.java  [line: 41]
line 41 is    `if(age == (isStudent() || isChild()))`

> Error: The operator == is undefined for the argument type(s) int,
>   boolean

Could someone explain why?

```
 public double confirmBooking(){
    double standardTicketPrice = 56.0;
    double standardMealPrice = 30.0;

    if(age == (isStudent() || isChild())){
    return standardTicketPrice / 2.0;
    }else{
    return standardTicketPrice * (20.0/100.0); 
    }

    if(age.equals(isChild())){
      return standardMealPrice / 2.0;
    }else{
     return standardMealPrice * (10.0/100.0); 
    }
  }// end method confirmBooking
```

Comment: could u give a lil more of code , with isChild() and isStudent() ?

Comment: @Sanjay   public boolean isChild(){
    if (age >= 5 && age <= 16){
      return true;
    }
    else {
      return false;
    }
  }
  
  public boolean isStudent(){
    if (id == true){
      return true;
    }
    else {
      return false;
    }
  }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primitive types are compared with `==`. You can't invoke the `equals` method on a primitive type. **Primitive types are not objects.** Another error is that you are directly comparing `boolean` and `int` value. They are not compatible.

Comment: Thank you for the propmt reply i tried both my mistake for not stating both errors File: Customer.java  [line: 41]
Error: The operator == is undefined for the argument type(s) int, boolean
Customer.java  [line: 47]
Error: Cannot invoke equals(boolean) on the primitive type int

Comment: Create `isChild(age)` and `isStudent(age)` methods which return whether a person is a child or a student depending on the age. As I have written in my post, you can't invoke a method on a primitive type. That's why you get an error - `Cannot invoke method on a primitive type`.

Comment: The method isStudent() in the type Customer is not applicable for the arguments (int)

Answer (score 1):

`int` and `boolean` are two different types, and can never be equal to each other. 
An int has 2^32 values, whereas a boolean has only two : `true` and `false`.

Your methods should be `isStudent(int age)` and `isChild(int age)`. They would return true or false depending on the age argument.

Comment: therefore if i set a standard price and wanted to apply discounts to it i wouldn't be able to attempt something like the above so it would decide whether it is or not a child or student then do the calculations? I'm sorry if my code is not really underlying what i'm trying to say but that's what i had in mind

Answer (score 1):

Try this instad of if(age == (isStudent() || isChild())

if(true == ((isStudent() || isChild()). isStudent and isChild methods return type shold be boolean.

You can't apply equal method from integer.

instead of if(age.equals(isChild())) apply similer way as if(true == ((isStudent() || isChild())

Answer (score 0):

You can't compare `int` and `double`.
You need just `if(isStudent() || isChild())` (inside these functions you already "checked whether the age given was between some given numbers").